# angularjs - $http post reqest in queue one by one

Tags: angularjs

I have hundred rows in my view. I would like to process all those rows one by one.
Every row has status

- Not Complete (by default)
- Complete
- Processing

I would like to change status of each row before and after finish processing in controller.
Before finishing I would like to change status to processing and after finishing, I like to change complete.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse ">
                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.fname}}</td>
                <td>{{item.lname}}</td>               

                <td>
                    <span ng-class="class{{item.id}}"></span>
                </td>
</tr>
```

in controller I have

```
$scope.startSending = function() {
    $scope.filteredItems.forEach(function(entry) {
       // Throwing Error! How can dynamically get value of scope variable
            $scope.'class'+entry.id = 'icon-eye-open';
        });

};
```

Please advise how can I get value of dynamical named variable from $scope above in controller.

I would like to update my database as well, If I add $http in foreach loop.

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data).success(successCallback);
```

it will send all 100 requests all together. Can I execute each request one after another in queue?
I want to send request in queue, it should not send second request before completion of first request etc...

any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With respect to `Please advise how can I get value of dynamical named variable from $scope above in controller.` the answer is Javascript and not AngularJS related. Just do:

```
$scope['class' + entry.id] = 'icon-eye-open';
```

With respect to queueing the $http requests, you want to check out the various asynchronous flow control solutions. I've used in a Node.js app caolan's `async` and it's very nice. You can find it in [github](https://github.com/caolan/async) and a fine tutorial is available [here](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice). I believe that in your case you need a [forEachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#forEachSeries).

(Please try to limit each post to 1 question or if not possible at least to N related questions.)

Comment: $scope['class' + entry.id] = 'icon-eye-open'; It is neither working nor throwing any error.

Comment: In your .forEach() loop check if 'entry' contains what you expect it to have (do a console.log() to see if entry.id exists)